# Android - How to make a non-debug .apk file?

Tags: android, apk

I have been using Eclipse to compile and run my development Android app.

Now I tried to submit my app for the first time to the google store, and it said I need to make a non-debug version of the .apk file.

How do I do that? :)

Thanks!

Comment: -1 no research effort. It's explained in the official documentation.

Comment: I just did a doc search, and I couldn't find it.  Could you provide a link?  The only reference I was able to find was in http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html, and you have to expand the March 2012 entry to see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on your app and then go to Android Tools > export unsigned application package, and then you have to sign that package using the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Note: you also need to remove the android:debuggable="true" flag from your manifest if it's there.

Comment: additionally one might want to read this https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html first!

Answer (score 4):

In android studio select **Build** > **Select Build Variant** and a build variants tab will show up, select release by clicking on the build variant (is should say debug if you are asking this question)

Comment: I tried this but then it didn't sign the APK file and I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really remember Eclipse but don't you have a Debug/Release option somewhere? I think you need to build a release version of your program by selecting Release somewhere in the options.