# Generate the apk file for an android application with debbugable option = False in the AndroidManifest.XML using CLI (Ionic)

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, command-line-interface, android-manifest

I am working on generating the apk file for an android app in a jenkins pipeline, using gradle and I am going to production. For security issues, I want to disable the debug mode.

1- Does gradle by default set debuggable to True ? (In a sense, if the option is not displayed in the AndroidManifest.XML file; does this mean that it is set to True ? )

2- Is there a way to set it to False from the beginning (I generate the android folder with the option, debbugable = False) ?

Please find below my build.gradle file generated using this command:

[image]

ionic capacitor add android

These are the steps, I am going through in order to get the build.gradle file :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You can follow this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831037/android-how-to-make-a-non-debug-apk-file

Comment: @PaolinoLAngeletti I am not using IDEs to build the apk file. ( I am using CLI in a jenkins pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

When there is no debuggable flag in the AndroidManifest then it means that the app is not debuggable.

If you structured the app project having two build types, `debug` and `release`, then while building the app the `android:debuggable` flag will be automatically set for you.

Build types can be specified in the app's build.gradle file, like this:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //by default, debuggable is true
        }
        release {
            // by default, debuggable is false
        }
    }
}
```

The debug build type will produce a manifest with the debug capability enabled whereas in the release build type there won't be any flag set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not sure, what do u mean by "If you structured the app project having two build types". Are you talking about the build.gradle config or something else ?

Comment: correct, I'm referring to the app's build.gradle file.

Comment: Understood! But the build.gradle file is generated, inside the android folder, when running this command: ''''ionic capacitor platform add android ''''. So, do we have to add some options to this command, in order to define the build types or am I missing something? I just added a photo to how my build.gradle file looks like.

Comment: the fact that you're using ionic to create the project wasn't mentioned in the question. Please update the question and provide an example of the generated build.gradle file. thanks

Comment: Oh ! ddnt think that ionic could make a difference. It is done, I added the build.gradle file. Thank uu

Comment: the file you posted is not the app's build.gradle file, instead is the project's root one

Comment: I just got confused, so I added the steps, i am going through to generate my build.gradle file. Please let me know if i am missing something